# maximize difference of elements in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Problem is to maximize difference of adjacent elements in array.

max(A[i]−A[j]) where 2≤i≤N for each i, j is the largest index less than i such that A [ j ] < A [ i ] .

**we are allowed to do AT MAX 1 swap**.

Let's say the array is {11,12,15}, then the power of the array is max((12−11),(15−12)) , which simplifies to max(1,3) which is equal to 3.

My approach: 1) when max element at 0 index and min element at last index.I will take max of difference between second maximum value and minimum value or maximum value and second minimum value. 2) otherwise difference between max and min(which will be possible with one swap).

Still my code is not working as expected.If possible please provide suggestion to make it working thanks.

inputs: 2(No of test case) 2(size of array) 9 10(array elements)
(output=1)

4(size of array) 2 3 4 1 (array elements)
(output=3)

code:

```
import java.util.*;
    class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

    //Scanner
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = s.nextInt();                 // Reading input from STDIN

    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
         int size = s.nextInt();
         int[] arr = new int[size];
         for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
         {
             arr[j]=s.nextInt();
         }

         int max1=arr[0];
         int max2=arr[1];
         int max1Index = 0;

         int min1 = arr[0];
         int min2 = arr[1];
         int minIndex = 0;

         for(int k=0;k<size;k++)
         {
             if(max1<arr[k])
             {
                 max2 = max1;
                 max1 = arr[k];
                 max1Index = k;
             }

             if(min1>arr[k])
             {
                 min2 = min1;
                 min1 = arr[k];
                 minIndex = k;
             }

         }
         int ans =0;
         if(max1Index == 0&& minIndex==size-1)
         {
             ans =Math.max((max1-min2), (max2-min1));
         }else
         {
             ans= max1-min1;
         }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }



    // Write your code here

}
}
```

Comment: What is "your code", how is it working?

Comment: added code in Question

Comment: Too localized. / Read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Please check your solution for **n=2**. Like for 1 2 3 1 as the input your output is 0 rather than 2. I think this is the only case where it fails.

Comment: I did't get you,for 1 2 3 1 input output is coming as expected 2.what do you mean by n=2??

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do it with an `IntStream`:

```
int ans = IntStream.range(1, size)
    .map(i -> arr[i] - arr[i-1])
    .max();
```

Or, if you don't want to consider negative differences:

```
int ans = IntStream.range(1, size)
    .map(i -> Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i-1]))
    .max();
```